# Sold her phone but forgot to uninstall her whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My friend forgot to uninstall her Whatsapp on her previous phone which was bought buy someone she doesn't know. When she try to use her whatsapp using the same number, she got a reply from the person who bought her phone. The person doesn't know how to uninstall the whatsapp. Any solution to remove that person from using whatsapp with her number?

Comment: If you still have contact to the buyer, and cooperation is given: Uninstall is as easy as going to *Settings › Apps*, scroll to the app's entry, tap it to open it, and then hit "clear data" plus "Uninstall". After that, buyer should also do a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) at least (to disconnect it from any other accounts such as Gmail etc, and have a "clean device").

Answer (score 5):

Please tell your friend to ALWAYS DO A FULL WIPE of the device before to sell it. This is very important for your privacy!

Anyway, please refer to the official whatsapp FAQ to solve your problem: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/24460358

> If you are not ready to activate WhatsApp on a new phone with the same
>   number, we can deactivate your account. Email us the phrase
>   "Lost/Stolen: Please deactivate my account" in the email body and
>   include your phone number in the full international format as
>   described here. Please note that we are not able to help you locate
>   your phone. Remote WhatsApp deactivation from another device is not
>   possible.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp is tied to the phone number. If she logs into another device, the new device takes over. The app will keep asking for verification in the old device. The app deactivates but all downloaded media files (voice messages included) remain on the device storage.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sell phones that you've used. Melt them down. Otherwise you are selling your personal data which can easily be recovered.

What she needs to do is install whatsapp on a new device using the same number that her old device had. That will lock the whatsapp on the old phone and force the new owner to put his/her new number in.